# What are the statistically most likely places to buy certain items from merchants?

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm looking to (eventually) get into crafting, and while I've saved a lot of jewels, gems, and runes, I'm lacking in certain magical equipment. Namely:

- sharkskin gloves
- vampirebone gloves
- sharkskin belts
- vampirefang belts
- mesh belts
- mithril coils
- demonhide boots
- wyrmhide boots

Rather than hoping for a bunch of these to drop, it would be much easier to buy them from merchants. But which are statistically most likely to sell these? I can't find any information about which vendors are most likely to sell specific items.

Comment: gambling is usually what I went with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the items that you need I'd recommend using only `Elite` items(more about `Normal`/`Exceptional`/`Elite` items [here](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/weaponsandarmor.shtml)) because it has the highest `ilvl`.

On the same page you can see the following:

> *Elite Items first appear late in Nightmare Difficulty and become more
>   common as you get to higher difficulty levels tied to monster levels.
>   Magic Elite Items can be found at the Vendors at higher Character and
>   Difficulty Levels. Rare Elite Items can be [Gambled](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/basics/gambling.shtml).*

So I'd recommend checking out vendors in Hell difficulty. If you need just cheap Elite items check some blacksmiths:

- Act 1

  - *`Charsi`*
- Act 2

  - *`Fara`*, *`Elzix`*
- Act 3

  - *`Asheara`*, *`Hratli`*, *`Ormus`*
- Act 4

  - *`Halbu`*, *`Jamella`*
- Act 5

  - *`Larzuk`*, *`Malah`*, *`Anya`*

These are the ones that sell armor, so you might find some gloves, belts and boots that you need.

You can also gamble these items, but it would cost a lot more(but the gambling page refreshes every time you look at it, so you won't need to create that many games and teleport between acts).

---

If you do have time and patience I'd recommend checking the vendors.

If you have enough gold go for gambling(a `Travincal` in Act 3 is an awesome spot for gold farming if you need it. I've heard about people making over 1 mil gold in 1 run).